# Assign code to the memory of the button created with code

Tags: c#, winforms

Hello I created a paragraph of code like this, but here is my problem. How can I do it now thanks.

I want to instantly assign code to the buttons I created here, I need to work with this code button and after giving it as an example of each button Shift1 =5 Shift2 =10 Shift3 =15 Shift4 =20 Shift5 =25 need to write. but in all the buttons it writes 25. The number of the buttons I created is variable. I was working on SQL. The buttons produce value by name

My Code;

```
    public int syc = 0;
    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        syc = 0;
        Button[] ara = new Button[5];
        for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
        {
            ara[i] = new Button();
            ara[i].Text = "Shift";
            ara[i].Size = new Size(50, 50);
            ara[i].Location = new Point(50, i * 50);
            this.Controls.Add(ara[i]);                
            ara[i].Click += Form1_Click;
            syc = syc + 5;
        }
    }

    private void  Form1_Click( object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        a(syc);
    }
    private int a(int b)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(b.ToString());
        return b ;
    }
```

Comment: ...and what is the problem?

Comment: Do what? Your question is very unclear, please explain. "How can I do it" is not a valid question.

Comment: "here is my problem"  *What* is your problem?  "How can I do it now"  How can you do *what*?  We can't read your mind.

Answer (score 0):

Right now all your button share the same function on click which use a shared variable syc. That is why they all fire the same value.

replace

```
ara[i].Click += Form1_Click;
syc = syc + 5;
```

by

```
var temp = i* 5;
ara[i].Click += (se, ev) => a(temp);
```

this will create a dedicated function for all buttons. note that the temp variable is mandatory as it will be captured by the lambda.

Comment: did not work, gave error;
Severity Code Description Project File Line Suppression State
Error CS0136 A local or parameter named 'sender' cannot be declared in this scope because that name is used in an enclosing local scope to define a local or parameter Deneme C:\Users\*******\Desktop\Deneme\Deneme\Form1.cs 33 Active.

///and I picked up the form1 click method

Comment: right my sender local variable conflict with the one in the enclosing function. Edited my answer to fit.

Comment: Thank you for all your help :)

Comment: mark as answer if it fits so that others may pick the code

Answer (score 0):

Controls have multipurpose property called "**Tag**". When creating the button, place the respective int value inside there and get it in the eventmethod from the sender, which is the button.